# How to lazy render large dataset based on scroll events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large `dataset` and was wondering how I can lazy render the `dataset`? I was able to render the data in view port. How do I render the remaining data as the user scrolls through the page?

So far in my custom binding I'm doing this to speed up my initial page load.

```
var elementRelativeHeight = $element.offset().top;
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

if(elementRelativeHeight > windowHeight) {
    //How do I register a callback so it template is rendered upon scroll?
} else {
    $("#mydiv").appendChild($element);
}
```

Comment: plenty of examples out on the net on lazy loading. Solution really depends on what the data is and how you need to fetch it.

Comment: I updated the title of my question. I'm familiar with lazy rendering, but not sure how to do it based on scroll events.

Comment: You can add an event listener and get how close the user is to the bottom of the screen. If they are close, lazy load another packet of data

Comment: I'm struggling to write that piece. If you want show me an example that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with large chunks of data to display, it is important to keep in mind that there's actually no point showing 1000 items in one go because if an item height is `50px` and you have a viewport height of `1000px` then you will be able to only see 20 items and the rest are hidden. So why not display this data slowly by loading few more data while you're scrolling the list.

Here is a complete example of this idea. By loading more data while you scroll down by counting how many items are outside the screen, If the count is lesser than 5 means you have few items left to scroll so it's safe to add more. This will also add a seemless experience so the user will never hit the edge unless there's nothing left

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [];
  /* How many items we load each iteration */
  var displayLimit = 30;
  var sensitivity = 300;
  var scrollTimeout = false;
  /* Keep track on the items being displayed */
  var displayData = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    data.push("Item - " + i);
  }

  var loadData = function() {

    /* [0] means using the javascript object than jquery.
       It is very important not to use $() in a loop, unless its
       absolutely necessary. Since this will cause severe performance
       issue later on. If it can be placed outside then put it outside.
     */
    var container = $(".items")[0]

    for (var i = 0; i < displayLimit; i++) {
      /* If the length is 20 means, index 0 to 19 are displayed
         and start at 20th index of the original data source
       */
      var currentIndex = displayData.length;

      /* check if it's not out of bounds */
      if (currentIndex > data.length) {
        break;
      }

      var item = data[currentIndex];

      displayData.push(item);

      var element = document.createElement("div");
      element.classList.add("item");
      element.innerHTML = item;

      container.appendChild(element);
    }
  };

  /* Load data at the beginning */
  loadData();

  $(".scrollable").scroll(function(event) {
    var edge = false;
    /* Height of the scrollable container */
    var height = $(event.target).height();
    /* Refers to how much you have scrolled */
    var scrollY = $(event.target).scrollTop();
    /* Amount of pixels of scrollable content */
    var scrollHeight = event.target.scrollHeight;

    /* If we happen to hit the edge but the timeout
       is still in effect, call the function regardless
     */
    if (height + scrollY == scrollHeight) {
      edge = true;
    }

    if (!scrollTimeout ||
      edge) {

      /* When dealing with loading while scrolling
       it is very important to limit how many times
       this event gets called. If this is not here,
       you will notice this callback gets called
       a `lot` of times. So we don't want this to cause
       a performance issue later on.
      */
      scrollTimeout = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        scrollTimeout = false;
      }, sensitivity);

      var count = 0;
      var toScroll = toScroll;
      var items = $(".items .item");

      /* Count how many items are outside the screen */
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        /* Refers to Y position of the element
           on your screen */
        var Y = $(item).offset().top;
        /* Since we're getting the items outside the
           screen we have to get the items that `are`
           outside the height of the screen +
           the scrolled amount */
        var currentY = height + scrollY;

        /* Check if this item is outside */
        if (Y > currentY) {
          count++;
        }

        /* There's no point to count anymore 
           if we wanted to loadMore() when there are
           5 items left to scroll */
        if (count > toScroll) {
          break;
        }
      }

      /* If there are 5 or less items to scroll
         loadMore() data
       */
      if (count <= 5) {
        loadData();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.scrollable {
  height: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="items">

  </div>
</div>
```